# Как получить данные из атрибута с разными значениями?

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

С помощью bs4 нужно получить текст из div с тегом “id”. У тега «id» значение может быть 1, 2 или 3. Нужно получить текст, если он равен 1 или 3

Кусок html кода, который повторяется с разными значениями:

```
<div class="group" id="1">
<b class="subjectClass">Нач.</b> ОРВ  <br/> Не опознано <br/>  В процессе

            <br/></div>
```

Пробовал:
a = soup.find_all(“div”, id=“1” or “3”)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

```
for tag in soup.find_all(class_="group") :
  id_value = tag.attrs.get("id")
  if id_value and id_value  in ('1', '2'):
      print(tag.contents[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем варианте никак потому что:

#### Необязательные открывающие теги

| Тег | Когда можно не писать |
| --- | --- |
| `<html>` | Если перед ним не идет `<!-- комментарий -->` |
| `<head>` | Если перед ним не идет `<!-- комментарий -->` |
| `<body>` | Если `body` начинается не с `<!-- комментария -->`, пробела, либо одного из тегов, который может быть и в `head` |
| `<tbody>` | Перед `<tr>`, если перед ним нет незакрытого `thead`, `tfoot` или другого `tbody` |
| `<colgroup>` | Перед `<col>`, если перед ним нет незакрытого другого `colgroup` |

#### Необязательные закрывающие теги

| Тег | Когда можно не писать |
| --- | --- |
| `</html>` | Если после него не идет `<!-- комментарий -->` |
| `</head>` | Если после него не идет `<!-- комментарий -->` или пробел |
| `</body>` | Если после него не идет `<!-- комментарий -->` |
| `</li>` | Перед `<li>` или `</ul>`/`</ol>` |
| `</dt>` | Перед `<dt>` или `<dd>` |
| `</dd>` | Перед `<dt>`, `<dd>` или концом родителя |
| `</p>` | Перед открывающим тегом любого [не-фразового потокового](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#kinds-of-content) («блочного» по-старому:) элемента, либо закрывающим тегом родительского элемента (если у того не [прозрачная](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#transparent-content-models) модель контента) |
| `</rt>` и `</rp>` | Перед `<rt>`, `<rp>` или `</ruby>` |
| `</optgroup>` | Перед `<optgroup>` или `</select>` |
| `</option>` | Перед `<option>`, `<optgroup>`, `</optgroup>` или `</select>` |
| `</colgroup>` | Если после него не идет `<!-- комментарий -->` или пробел |
| `</caption>` | Если после него не идет `<!-- комментарий -->` или пробел |
| `</thead>` | Перед `<tbody>` или `<tfoot>` |
| `</tbody>` | Перед другим `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>` или `</table>` |
| `</tfoot>` | Перед `</table>` |
| `</tr>` | Перед `<tr>` или концом родителя |
| `</td>` и `</th>` | Перед `<td>`, `<th>` или концом родителя |

В связи с вышеизлоенным приведите Ваш html к нормальному виду (тэги закройте)

```html
<div class="group" id="1">
<b class="subjectClass">Нач.</b> ОРВ  <br/> Не опознано <br/>  В процессе

            <br/></div>
<div class="group" id="2">
<b class="subjectClass">Нач.</b> ОРВ  <br/> Не опознано <br/>  В процессе

            <br/></div>
            <div class="group" id="3">
            <b class="subjectClass">Нач.</b> ОРВ  <br/> Не опознано <br/>  В процессе
            
                        <br/></div>
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

text = """

<div class="group" id="1">
<b class="subjectClass">Нач.</b> ОРВ  <br/> Не опознано <br/>  В процессе

            <br/></div>
<div class="group" id="2">
<b class="subjectClass">Нач.</b> ОРВ  <br/> Не опознано <br/>  В процессе

            <br/></div>
            <div class="group" id="3">
            <b class="subjectClass">Нач.</b> ОРВ  <br/> Не опознано <br/>  В процессе
            
                        <br/></div>
"""
soup = Soup(text, 'html.parser')

print(
    soup.find_all(
        id=re.compile(r'[13]')
    )
)
# Или так
print(
    soup.find_all(
        id=lambda x: x in ['1', '3']
    )
)
```

```
[<div class="group" id="1">
<b class="subjectClass">Нач.</b> ОРВ  <br/> Не опознано <br/>  В процессе

            <br/></div>, <div class="group" id="3">
<b class="subjectClass">Нач.</b> ОРВ  <br/> Не опознано <br/>  В процессе
            
                        <br/></div>]
```